# Is there a more simple way to integrate shopify store admin with other websites?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, sharetribe

I'm just a beginner. I have created a website. Now I want shopify store admins to come and sell on my website. To do that I'm gonna need some way to have store admins provide me their store data like products. Shopify provides a way to do that by creating an app which provides scopes and access token. They can give me access token and I can run some REST apis to get that data.
But I want to simplify this process. I want to create an interface which asks for store admins permission to provide me data and then it automatically integrates. Like you install apps on shopify.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very precise and relatively easy job to do here. You want to create what is called a Sales Channel App for Shopify. With that installed in any merchant store, you would have available to you a JSON representation of just the products they want you to sell on your website. As a bonus, every time you do sell a product of theirs on your website, you have the ability to complete the order with fulfillment aspects and their store. It is all automatic as you wish, and works a peach. Try it! You might end up with a huge success story and a very in-demand App in the Shopify App store.